# How to detect browser type in HTML5 or Javascript for playing mp3 instead of webm in Safari/IE browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari

I have created a survey in Qualtrics wherein I play webm audios. However in Safari webm doesn't play and for IE the user needs to install [this](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/webmmf/) Google plugin. I was wondering if there is a code in preferably HTML(5) or even javascript which can detect type of the browser and if it's Safari or IE then play the mp3 version of the audio(which we have on the server as well). Also please let me know if there are better solutions than this for tackling the problem of playing audio in various browsers.

```
The second auditory story is titled, &ldquo;The Most Precious Possession.&rdquo; Press the &ldquo;Play Story&rdquo; button to begin listening to the story; after you have finished listening to the story, you will answer a set of questions about the story.
<div>
<audio controls="" id="audio3" style="display:none"><source src="http://langcomplab.net/Most_Precious_Possession_Master.webm" style="width:50%" type="audio/webm" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support this audio format.</audio>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div><button name="play" onclick="disabled=true" style="height:25px; width:200px" type="button">Play Story</button></div>
```

Here's the javascript in Qualtrics which means I cannot change it much.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/
    var aud = document.getElementById('audio3');
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        if((element.type == "button") && (element.name == "play"))
        {
            aud.play();
        }
    }


});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or JSBin with a sample of what you're trying to do? Or perhaps provide the website where this code is running?

Comment: Well, the problem is you have to take the whole survey till come to the audio part https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_exkWSVu4vGr6tnL

Comment: What browsers are you intending on supporting?

Comment: it doesn't support IE and Safari as webm doesn't play in either. So I was thinking of detecting Safari/IE and play mp3 version instead of webm in those case. The reason I didn't go with mp3 is that sometimes plays and sometimes not in Chrome and Firefox!

Comment: Sorry what specific browser versions. IE8+ Firefox X? Whats the oldest browser you need to support?

Comment: If you need to support the latest and greatest then just do it all with MP3. Try this http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all  It should work in every browser without an issue. You might have something else causing an issue.

Comment: This is a survey that is going to be taken by people with various browsers. So essentially anything out there including all the possible versions.

Comment: @cgatian am I correct in my understanding that it either plays ogg file or mp3 file? http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide both an mp3 and webm sources and you set the type attribute properly, the browser can select the one it supports. So just add the mp3 one. I would put the mp3 one first since some old Safari browsers only use the first one (and they supported mp3), but otherwise the browsers will select the first one they can support based on the type.

```
<audio controls="" id="audio3" style="display:none">
    <source src="http://langcomplab.net/Most_Precious_Possession_Master.mp3"
       style="width:50%" type="audio/mp3" />
    <source src="http://langcomplab.net/Most_Precious_Possession_Master.webm"
       style="width:50%" type="audio/webm" />
    Your browser doesn&#39;t support this audio format.
</audio>
```

See additional information on MDN which applies to both audio and video.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: well, that is what I already went with in my previous posts in stackoverflow. However I will select yours as an answer. Could you please take a look at here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419344/why-almost-longer-audio-dont-play-in-chrome-while-they-play-in-ie-firefox-and