# Why this code doesn't alert the browser type?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, onclick

Can you tell me what I am missing in writing this code?

```
<button onclick="getBrowserName()">You Browser Name?</button>
<script>
    function getBrowserName()
{

    //Uses external interface to reach out to browser and grab browser useragent info.
    var browserAgent:String = ExternalInterface.call("function getBrowser(){return navigator.userAgent;}");
    //Determines brand of browser using a find index. If not found indexOf returns (-1).
    if(browserAgent != null && browserAgent.indexOf("Firefox")>= 0) 
    {
        alert("Firefox");
    }
    else if(browserAgent != null && browserAgent.indexOf("Safari")>= 0)
    {
        alert("Safari");
    }
    else if(browserAgent != null && browserAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>= 0)
    {
        alert("IE");
    }
    else if(browserAgent != null && browserAgent.indexOf("Opera")>= 0)
    {
        alert("Opera");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Undefined");
    }
    return 0;
}

</script>
```

Comment: I hope there's a good reason for browser detection. Its best to use feature detection whenever you can.

Comment: @cgatian I have a good reason for doing so however the code is not working!

Comment: Why do you need this `var browserAgent:String = ExternalInterface.call("function getBrowser(){return navigator.userAgent;}");` ? Just do `window.navigator.userAgent`

Comment: Just because a browser doesn't have one of the expected strings in its user agent string, you call it undefined. More accurate might be "Not a browser I care about" perhaps? ;-) There is a list of over 80 browsers [*here*](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/browsers_list.php3), and a database of thousands of UA strings [*here*](http://www.user-agents.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not quite sure what the follow code should be doing. Are you sure its correct?

```
    var browserAgent:String = 
ExternalInterface.call("function getBrowser(){return navigator.userAgent;}");
```

I would expect this code to simply look like this:

```
var browserAgent = navigator.userAgent;
```

Below is a example with this change.
http://jsbin.com/lukasere/1/edit

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful with browser detection! It's so unreliable!

Comment: I need it for playing various audio type depending on the browser type as asked in my previous SO post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398911/how-to-detect-browser-type-in-html5-or-javascript-for-playing-mp3-instead-of-web

Comment: I just realized this code is not reliable as is telling Chrome in Ubuntu is Safari!!!

Comment: @MonaJalal That's the problem with browser detection.

Comment: How come hasn't been yet fixed? #weird

Comment: @MonaJalal Well, see the debate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection): it's not a problem with "fixing" something, per se, but really about best practice and [future-proofing your code](http://ejohn.org/blog/future-proofing-javascript-libraries/).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a few things wrong here.

1. `var browserAgent: String`: it appears that you're using [actionscript](/questions/tagged/actionscript) syntax, but JS uses dynamic typing, so `var` is all you need. There's no need to explicitly define the variable's data type, and if you try to do it this way in JS, it's going to give you syntax errors.
2. `ExternalInterface.call`: this is another carryover from ActionScript: you don't need this. In fact, it won't work at all because there's no `ExternalInterface` class in standard JS.
3. Your `getBrowser()` function is unnecessary. You're setting `browserAgent` equal to the result of calling a function from an `ExternalInterface`, but you can do this directly: `var browserAgent = window.navigator.userAgent`.

When I fixed those things, it worked fine.

Next time, I would recommend checking the browser console, because, if nothing is happening, the errors that appear there will help you solve your issue nine times out of ten.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/cPwkV/)

Comment: Your first point is wrong. When/where the function is declared is totally irrelevant, as long as it exists in the global scope at the time the button is pressed.

Comment: Even a `var` in that place would've created a global variable.

Comment: @Bergi Never mind; I was thinking of its scope only [within the JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).

Answer (score 2):

If you replace this line

```
var browserAgent:String = ExternalInterface.call("function getBrowser(){return navigator.userAgent;}");
```

with this line:

```
var browserAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
```

Then your script works fine on my side.

However, the criteria you use to test the engine are not precise. Have a look at this:
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

There are many browsers that will tell you Firefox even if they another brand. But they are based on each other or they use a specific engine that is built in other browsers too.

If I use your script with a Chrome browser, it says "Safari" instead of "undefined".

About the punctuation: I know of only two places in Javascript where to use the double point:

- the conditional operator `a = b ? c : d;`
- the attribute - value assignment in object notation: `{ name : value }`

Your code line containing `:String = ExternalInterface...` reminds me rather on ActionScript (?).